# Error myFunction(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, bluebird

I have the following module that basically performs a GET request to Google:

```
// my-module.js
var request = require('request');
var BPromise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = get;

function get() {
    return BPromise.promisify(doRequest);
}

function doRequest(callback) {
    request.get({
        uri: "http://google.com",
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(null, body);
        }
        else {
            callback(err, null);
        }
    });
}
```

And I want to use this module like so:

```
//use-module.js
var myModule = require('./my-module');

myModule().then(function (body) {
     console.log(body);
});
```

The error I'm facing is the following:

`myModule(...).then is not a function.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BPromise.promisify(doRequest)` does not call `doRequest`, but returns a "promisified" version of that function. You should do that once, not at each call. This should work:

```
module.exports = BPromise.promisify(doRequest);
```